# Reporting Services caching - what is its security impact?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Where I work, we have SSRS 2008 R2. I'm a newbie at it. The datawarehouse and SSRS is on the same machine. The datasources use Windows Authentication and the users have browser role access using Windows Authentication with their domain account. To use caching, I have to save login credentials on the datasource. I have a specific SQL server login for running reports. How does this impact the security of the reports? Is it now lessened because one level of security has been removed?

If the datasource is moved to different machine from SSRS, will I have to save the login credentials on the datasource anyway?

AD credentials don't specify what tables you can access anyway, right? Am I worrying over nothing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Mike,
You are correct in that you have removed a layer of security by setting the login in the DataSource for caching. You could potentially have a user access a report that would have otherwise been limited by security set on the SQL server side.

If it makes you feel better, I had to do the same thing for my company.

You can, however, *limit who has access to that DataSource*. Go to the Management screen for that DataSource and then the Security tab. Here you can limit who has access to this datasource. If you're not too familiar with SSRS security, you can set your user roles by clicking the gear widget icon on the top left of the screen and going to Site Settings>Security.

To answer your second question, if the Data Source is on the same domain I would expect Windows Authentication to still function seamlessly. If it goes outside the domain you might have issues.

For your final question, you can Map users in SQL server security on a per table basis. I've only seen this used to grant specific authorities and not limit it.

I think you're better off NOT giving your users SQL server access, limiting their access to reports and Data Sources via SSRS and using the dedicated access account for Data Sources!

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll be switching to a SQL login for running the reports and look into reducing the access of the users to the SQL server.

Comment: No problem. Shoot me a message if you need a hand.